# how to implement youtube show/hide memorable sidebar?

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, laravel

I'd like to make a sidebar with show/hide memorable function like Youtube sidebar.
I'v tried cookie but seems cant work with laravel Cookie API.
Anyone has any good ideal? i would be very thankful:)

Comment: Show some code that illustrates what you have tried or where you think the error is...

Comment: i'v tried cookie method,but seems the frontend cookie cant interact with the backend cookie